# Export infinite looping GIFs by default

Tags: export, animation, gif-format

```
frames=Table[Plot[Sin[x(1+a x)],{x,0,6}],{a,0,2,0.2}];
Export["test.gif",frames]
```

The above code runs in version 9.0 to get a infinite looping GIF animation, but in recent versions it only loops once.
I know I can specify the option `"AnimationRepetitions" -> Infinity`. Can this option be the default when exporting GIF?
I have tried `SetOptions[Export, "AnimationRepetitions" -> Infinity]`, it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm unclear what you are looking for exactly. If I had a number of animations to export, I would write a simple `myExport` routine that would set the option for me. If you need it every session, you could put the definition in `init.m`.  It doesn't seem much different to me that `SetOptions` (if that actually worked).

Comment: I also struggle with this ever since they switched the default behavior. Is there a specific reason they changed this? In any case, I will definitely use your trick @MichaelE2 . Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The final internal `` System`Convert`CommonGraphicsDump`exportImageListToGIF `` does not have `Options` and outer `` System`Convert`CommonGraphicsDump`exportImageListToRasterFormat `` has but handles other raster formats so it is not desirable to affect them.

What can be done is to re-register gif export. That needs to be done once per session, e.g. in `init.m`:

```
Begin["System`ConvertersDump`"]

ImportExport`RegisterExport[
   "GIF",
   System`Convert`CommonGraphicsDump`ExportElementsToRasterFormat[
   "GIF", ##, "AnimationRepetitions" -> Infinity (*here's the patch*)] &,
   "Sources" -> {"Convert`CommonGraphics`"},
   "DefaultElement" -> Automatic,
   "Options" -> 
  SortBy[{"AnimationDuration", "AnimationRepetitions", Background, 
    "Comments", "ControlAppearance", "DisplayDurations", Dithering, 
    "FrameRate", ImageSize, "Interlaced", 
    "PreserveManipulateInitialization", "TransparentColor"}, ToString],
   "BinaryFormat" -> True
 ]

End[]
```

or you'd need to modify `$InstallationDirectory\SystemFiles\Formats\GIF\Export.m` but modifying installation dir is not recommended.

Comment: Thank you. I had a related problem with version 11.2. It seems to me that that value of `"AnimationRepetitions"` is simply ignored. For whatever value I gave it, the resulting animation ran exactly twice. Like [here](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/17460/282). Running your snippet fixed that, and (at least in my browser) also fixed the problem.